# Can anyone with tag wiki edit privileges edit/remove the “search-console” tag?

Tags: discussion

The google-search-console is the primary tag used for asking questions related to the Search Console. However, I've noticed a few questions with the "search-console" tag which is redundant. I do not have the tag wiki edit privileges, so can anyone with the privileges delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good catch! Tags [get created](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) by users just by adding them to questions, and sometimes they don't notice there's already an existing similar tag.

Tags which don't have any questions will [automatically be deleted within a 24-hour period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags). So the solution is just to remove the problematic tag from every question that added it by editing them. The `Edit tags` link makes this pretty easy to do.

I've gone ahead and removed the `search-console` tag from all the questions using it, so in about a day, the tag should no longer be available on the site (if nobody else creates and uses it again).